# Can I generate bivariate normal random variables with correlation 1 using Cholesky factorization?

Tags: r

Is it possible to set a `correlation = 1` using the cholesky decomposition technique?

```
set.seed(88)
mu<- 0
sigma<-1
x<-rnorm(10000, mu, sigma)
y<-rnorm(10000, mu, sigma)
MAT<-cbind(x,y)
cor(MAT[,1],MAT[,2])

#this doesn't work because 1 makes it NOT positive-definite. any number 0 to .99 works
correlationMAT<- matrix(1,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)

U<-chol(correlationMAT)
newMAT<- MAT %*% U 
cor(newMAT[,1], newMAT[,2])  #.....but I want to make this cor = 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to create variables with `cor` 1, that's pretty easy... `x <- rnorm(10000)`, `y <- constant * x` where `constant` is anything you want that's greater than 0. But if there's noise, then the correlation will be less than 1.

Comment: @Gregor  - But I want to transform to using the chol or something similar.

Comment: @user3022875 Why would it matter how you did it? 1 is a pathological case, but it's a trivial one.

Comment: If you want to use matrix multiplication you can do `MAT %*% M` where `M <- matrix(c(1, 0, constant, 0), 2)`, and `constant` is > 0. But, once again, it won't matter what the second column of `MAT` is... if your answer depends on that second column then the correlation won't be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can, by using **pivoted** Cholesky factorization.

```
correlationMAT<- matrix(1,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
U <- chol(correlationMAT, pivot = TRUE)
#Warning message:
#In chol.default(correlationMAT, pivot = TRUE) :
#  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite

U
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    0    0
#attr(,"pivot")
#[1] 1 2
#attr(,"rank")
#[1] 1
```

Note, `U` has identical columns. If we do `MAT %*% U`, we replicate `MAT[, 1]` twice, which means the second random variable will be identical to the first one.

```
newMAT<- MAT %*% U

cor(newMAT)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
```

You don't need to worry that two random variables are identical. Remember, this only means they are identical after standardization (to `N(0, 1)`). You can rescale them by different standard deviation, then shift them by different mean to make them different.

---

Pivoted Cholesky factorization is very useful. My answer for this post: [Generate multivariate normal r.v.'s with rank-deficient covariance via Pivoted Cholesky Factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346238/4891738) gives a more comprehensive picture.