# Cholesky decomposition failure for my correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-factorization, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to use `chol()` to find the Cholesky decomposition of the correlation matrix below.  Is there a maximum size I can use that function on?  I am asking because I get the following:

```
d <-chol(corrMat)
Error in chol.default(corrMat) : 
  the leading minor of order 61 is not positive definite
```

but, I can decompose it for less than 60 elements without a problem (even when it contains the 61st element of the original):

```
> d  <-chol(corrMat[10:69, 10:69])
> d  <-chol(corrMat[10:70, 10:70])
Error in chol.default(corrMat[10:70, 10:70]) : 
  the leading minor of order 61 is not positive definite
```

Here is the matrix:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0F1yWDNKi2vNkJHMDVHLWh4WjA

Comment: @zheyuan li That works in that it gives me an answer but I do not understand the output.  I intend to use this for Monte Carlo simulation and, from what I am reading about pivot, the output is in a different order from the original matrix.  Is it still useable?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not size, but numerical rank!

```
d <- chol(corrMat, pivot = TRUE)

dim(corrMat)
#[1] 72 72

attr(d, "rank")
#[1] 62
```

`corrMat` is not positive-definite. Ordinary Cholesky factorization will fail, but pivoted version works.

The correct Cholesky factor here can be obtained (see [Correct use of pivot in Cholesky decomposition of positive semi-definite matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43121059/4891738))

```
r <- attr(d, "rank")
reverse_piv <- order(attr(d, "pivot"))
d[-(1:r), -(1:r)] <- 0
R <- d[, reverse_piv]
```

Whether this is acceptable depends on your context. It might need corresponding adjustment to your other code.

Pivoted Cholesky factorization can do many things that sound impossible for a deficient, non-invertible covariance matrix, like

- sampling ([Generate multivariate normal r.v.'s with rank-deficient covariance via Pivoted Cholesky Factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346238/4891738));
- least squares ([linear regression by solving normal equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601794/fit-many-formulae-at-once-faster-options-than-lapply/38604244#38604244))

Comment: @zheyuan li I like your answer but I do not yet know if it is the right one.  I do not understand from reading the documentation what the pivot option is doing.  I am using d to generate Monte Carlo simulations for a portfolio of assets.  So, I generate a bunch of random normal, adjust them by their corresponding vols and then pass the result through d.  If I do this with your matrix R, am I losing any information about my portfolio (will the resulting returns have the correct correlations)?  How does the reordering of the pivot allow for the Cholesky decomposition to work?