# Correct use of pivot in Cholesky decomposition of positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-factorization, matrix-decomposition

I don't understand how to use the `chol` function in R to factor a positive semi-definite matrix. (Or I do, and there's a bug.) The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chol.html) states:

> If pivot = TRUE, then the Choleski decomposition of a positive semi-definite x can be computed. The rank of x is returned as attr(Q, "rank"), subject to numerical errors. The pivot is returned as attr(Q, "pivot"). It is no longer the case that t(Q) %*% Q equals x. However, setting pivot <- attr(Q, "pivot") and oo <- order(pivot), it is true that t(Q[, oo]) %*% Q[, oo] equals x ...

The following example seems to belie this description.

```
> x <- matrix(1, nrow=3, ncol=3)
> Q <- chol(x, pivot=TRUE)
> oo <- order(attr(Q, 'pivot'))
> t(Q[, oo]) %*% Q[, oo]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    3
```

The result is not `x`. Am I using the pivot incorrectly?

Comment: It's a very helpful answer @李哲源ZheyuanLi! Note that you could use R's negative indexing in `Q[-(1:r): -(1:r)] <- 0` to tidy up and skip the `if` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For full rank input, i.e., a positive-definite matrix `x`, we need

```
Q <- chol(x, TRUE)
oo <- order(attr(Q, 'pivot'))
unpivQ <- Q[, oo]
all.equal(crossprod(unpivQ), x)
```

For a **valid** rank-deficient input, i.e., a positive semi-definite matrix `x` (indefinite matrix with negative eigen values are illegal, but not checked in `chol`), remember to zero deficient trailing diagonal block:

```
Q <- chol(x, TRUE)
r <- attr(Q, 'rank')
if (r < nrow(x)) Q[(r+1):nrow(x), (r+1):nrow(x)] <- 0
oo <- order(attr(Q, 'pivot'))
unpivQ <- Q[, oo]
all.equal(crossprod(unpivQ), x)
```

Some people call this a 'bug' of `chol`, but actually it is a feature of the underlying LAPACK routine `dpstrf`. The factorization proceeds till the first diagonal element which is below a tolerance, leaving the trailing matrix simply untouched on exit.

---

Thanks to Ian for the following observation:

*You could use R's negative indexing in `Q[-(1:r), -(1:r)] <- 0` to skip the `if` statement.*

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. Nevertheless, while I wouldn't call it a bug of `chol` itself, I do think it's a documentation bug. The `x` matrix of the original question is a valid semi-pos-def input AFAICS.